# SQL oracle error on select inside select

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

This return single-row query subquery returns more than one row

```
select E.NO_ENCAN, E.NOM_ENC, TE.DESC_TYPE_ENC as TYPE_ENC, 
      (select sum(ITEM.MNT_VALEUR_ITE) from ENCAN left join ITEM on ITEM.NO_ENCAN = ENCAN.NO_ENCAN group by ENCAN.NO_ENCAN) as SOMME_ITEMS, 
       count(distinct INV.NOM_UTILISATEUR_INVITE) as NOMBRE_INVITES
  from ENCAN E
    left join TYPE_ENCAN TE on TE.CODE_TYPE_ENC = E.CODE_TYPE_ENC
    left join INVITE INV on INV.NO_ENCAN = E.NO_ENCAN
  group by E.NO_ENCAN, E.NOM_ENC, TE.DESC_TYPE_ENC
  order by E.NO_ENCAN;
```

And if I add order by in the subquery, it returns a missing right parenthesis.

Anyone can give me any clues on what's going on?

By the way, I know that keyword/word are inversed uppercase/lowercase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a correlated subquery rather than a `group by` in the subselect.  This also means that the subquery is not needed.  So, this is probably what you are trying to write:

```
select E.NO_ENCAN, E.NOM_ENC, TE.DESC_TYPE_ENC as TYPE_ENC, 
      (select sum(ITEM.MNT_VALEUR_ITE)
        from ITEM
        where ITEM.NO_ENCAN = ENCAN.NO_ENCAN
       ) as SOMME_ITEMS, 
      count(distinct INV.NOM_UTILISATEUR_INVITE) as NOMBRE_INVITES
from ENCAN E left join
     TYPE_ENCAN TE
     on TE.CODE_TYPE_ENC = E.CODE_TYPE_ENC left join
     INVITE INV
     on INV.NO_ENCAN = E.NO_ENCAN
group by E.NO_ENCAN, E.NOM_ENC, TE.DESC_TYPE_ENC
order by E.NO_ENCAN;
```

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing more about your schema and data, it looks to me like the issue is the 'group by ENCAN.NO_ENCAN'

I don't think you need the group by, or it is causing you issue.

Comment: The issue doesn't lie in the group by. If that grouping would only ever return one row, that would be valid. A subquery such as this can only be used in the select list if it returns a single value and that value is intended to be the same for every row returned.

Answer (score 1):

If I am correctly understanding what you are trying to accomplish, I believe the subquery is unnecessary. You should just put an analytic on the SUM() call.

```
SELECT e.no_encan
      ,e.nom_enc
      ,te.desc_type_enc AS type_enc
      ,SUM(item.mnt_valeur_ite) OVER (PARTITION BY e.no_encan) somme_items
      ,COUNT(DISTINCT inv.nom_utilisateur_invite) AS nombre_invites
  FROM encan e
  LEFT JOIN type_encan te ON te.code_type_enc = e.code_type_enc
  LEFT JOIN invite INV ON inv.no_encan = e.no_encan
 GROUP BY e.no_encan, e.nom_enc, te.desc_type_enc
 ORDER BY e.no_encan;
```

Details can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions163.htm), although I would really suggest reading more about [Analytic Functions in Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions001.htm#i81407).

Answer (score 0):

Your inner select statement is returning more than one row. Try adding a WHERE clause to limit your select to return one row.

```
select sum(ITEM.MNT_VALEUR_ITE) from ENCAN left join ITEM on ITEM.NO_ENCAN = ENCAN.NO_ENCAN 
**WHERE ENCAN.NO_ENCAN = '1234'**
group by ENCAN.NO_ENCAN
```

Comment: That will certainly limit the subquery, but I don't think it will accomplish what the query is intended to do. It looks like the report should be able to dynamically return the sum for all rows in encan at once.

Answer (score 0):

The `Group by  ENCAN.NO_ENCAN` is causing the issue. Since you are not selecting that column, you don't need to group by that.

Comment: This makes no sense. He is returning the SUM() of a column, but that has nothing to do with the proper grouping. Based on my guess at his data model, he is using the correct column for the grouping, just the wrong syntax (see my answer for the correct `PARTITION BY` statement).

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
with INVITE_ROLLUP as
(
    select ENCAN.NO_ENCAN, sum(ITEM.MNT_VALEUR_ITE) as NOMBRE_INVITES
    from ENCAN
    left join ITEM on ITEM.NO_ENCAN = ENCAN.NO_ENCAN
    group by ENCAN.NO_ENCAN
)
select 
  E.NO_ENCAN, 
  E.NOM_ENC, 
  TE.DESC_TYPE_ENC as TYPE_ENC, 
  INVITE_ROLLUP.NOMBRE_INVITES AS NOMBRE_INVITES
from ENCAN E
left join TYPE_ENCAN TE on TE.CODE_TYPE_ENC = E.CODE_TYPE_ENC
left join INVITE INV on INV.NO_ENCAN = E.NO_ENCAN
left join INVITE_ROLLUP ON E.NO_ENCAN = INVITE_ROLLUP.NO_ENCAN
group by E.NO_ENCAN, E.NOM_ENC, TE.DESC_TYPE_ENC
order by E.NO_ENCAN;
```